# passport component registration field (MODULE_NOT_FOUND) after mounting loopback 3 inside loopback4

Tags: loopback, loopback4

I am trying to upgrade from loopback 3 to loopback 4 using "mounting strategy" according to the documentation.

while trying to run the app using npm start, i am getting the following error:

> > > node -r source-map-support/register .
>
> Cannot start the application. { Error: Cannot find module
>   '../../node_modules/loopback-component-passport/lib/models/utils.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Data\myComp\app\myapp_docker\services\myapp_auth\lb3app\server\utils\providerUtils.js:2:15)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Data\myComp\app\myapp_docker\services\fauth\lb3app\server\server.js:6:25)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1

I checked and i have the module in the node_modules directory and the utils.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to search in all my app files for the string "node_modules" and I found that the relative path for that directory was incorrect. had to add one more "../" before the node_modules.